# Can't read length of array in JSX (React-Redux)

Tags: arrays, react-redux, mapstatetoprops

Simple enough question.  I am trying to read the value of the "length" variable inside this array of objects (See Image 1)

[image]

**MY CODE**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

    const lecture = state.firestore.ordered.lectures;
    const length = lecture.length;

    return {

        length: length,

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**WHILE WRITING THIS QUESTION I FOUND THE SOLUTION:**

**SOLUTION CODE**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {


    const length = state.firestore.ordered.lectures && state.firestore.ordered.lectures.length;



    return {

        length: length,

    }
}
```